# Can't generate more than ~8000 RPM from Locust

Tags: load-testing, locust

I'm using Locust to load test my web servers. I'm running Locust in distributed mode. The worker nodes are written in Java, and use the Locust/Java port using [locust4j](https://github.com/myzhan/locust4j). The master node and the worker nodes are containerized, our orchestrator is Kubernetes. When I want to spin up more workers, I'm doing it from there.

The problem that I'm running into is that no matter how many users I add, or worker nodes I add, I can't seem to generate more than ~8000 RPM. This is confirmed by the Locust web frontend, as well as the metrics I'm collecting from my web server.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

I've attached an image of timings I've collected. The snapshots are from running the load test for 60 seconds, I'm timing it from a stopwatch. [image]

Answer (score 2):

The usual culprit in these kinds of situations is your servers can't handle more than that. In my experience, the behavior you'll see client side as the servers get overwhelmed is you'll start to see a slow but steady increase in response times. This is one big reason why Locust includes those in the metrics it shows you.

Based on what I'm seeing in your screenshots, this is most likely the case for you. You have some very low minimum times but your average, median, and 90%iles are a lot higher than your minimums; your maximums are very significantly higher than those. Without seeing your charts I can't know for sure but that's a big red flag.

For more things to look out for, check out this question in the FAQ (especially see the list of server stats to investigate):

https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps

Comment: Thanks for your response, I hadn't seen that FAQ. I tried manually scaling up my web services, and it didn't resolve the problem, but it's possible something else in the pipe is causing the problem, so I'll start investigating that.